# Compiling Kernel: Can't change config through make menuconfig ncurses application

Tags: makefile, kernel, ncurses

Make menuconfig's ncurses menu is not allowing me to input up or down arrows to actually change my configuration: I just see escaped ascii characters polluting the terminal. Eg:

```
^[OB^[OB^[OA
```

I have to hit `Ctrl-C` to exit the menuconfig application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much hunting and changing of terminal environment variables, I found this bug report:

https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/32055

Running `/usr/bin/make menuconfig` started a working ncurses menuconfig application that I could use to change my kernel configuration.

Comment: In my case, I tried to start `make menuconfig` in tmux session and it didn't work. I exited tmux, it worked.